# Android JSON Parsing JSONArray

Tags: android, json

Why I am getting that NewsApp has no data? Why JSONArray not displaying data?

This is the code-

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
        super.onPostExecute(o);

        try {

            Toast.makeText(NewsActivity.this, "Response: " + response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());

            jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("NewsApp");

            Log.i("News",jsonArray.toString());


            for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){

                JSONObject jObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                NewsInfo newsInfo = new NewsInfo();

                //newsInfo.sourceName = jObj.getString("name");
                newsInfo.author = jObj.getString("author");
                newsInfo.title = jObj.getString("title");
                newsInfo.description = jObj.getString("description");
                newsInfo.url = jObj.getString("url");
                newsInfo.urlImage = jObj.getString("urlToImage");
                newsInfo.publishedAt = jObj.getString("publishedAt");

                newsInfoArrayList.add(newsInfo);

            }
```

Comment: Can you provide us the log content please?

Comment: Pleas add your json to question